# join 3 tables if 3rd table does not have that value

Tags: mysql, sql

Table 1

id , userid, eventid , name

table 2

eventid , zoneid , userid

table 3

eventid , userid, status

if all three table having the eventid means i dont want to select that record (i mean if table 3 have the eventid), else i need to select records

i tried my query

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    `table1` c1 
    INNER JOIN `table2` c2 ON c2.eventid = c1.eventid  
    LEFT JOIN table3 c3 ON c3.eventid = c1.eventid 
WHERE 
    c2.zoneid=2 
    AND c1.active='1' 
GROUP BY 
    c1.eventid
```

Answer (score 3):

Add a where clause where there is no c3:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table1` c1 
INNER JOIN `table2` c2 ON c2.eventid = c1.eventid  
LEFT JOIN table3 c3 ON c3.eventid = c1.eventid 
WHERE c2.zoneid=2 AND c1.active='1' 
AND c3.id IS NULL
group by c1.eventid
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    `table1` c1 
    INNER JOIN `table2` c2 ON c2.eventid = c1.eventid  
WHERE 
    c2.zoneid=2 
    AND c1.active='1' 
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table3 c3 WHERE c3.eventid = c1.eventid)
GROUP BY 
    c1.eventid
```

Applying a WHERE-condition (like some of the other answers suggest) on a table that has been joined through a LEFT/RIGHT OUTER JOIN will actually make it a regular join.
The other examples that have been posted ask c1.eventid to equal c3.eventid, and c3.eventid to be NULL - good chance that the result will be not what you expect, depending on how the database treats `c1.eventid = c3.eventid` if both are NULL (I'd have to read up on that).

Comment: It seems you misread the other answers. The only criteria in their where clauses on the outer joined table is `id is not null`. This gives exactly what's needed: table1 + table2 where not exists table3. However, I still like your approach better. I think it's more readable, because it actually says: read from table1 and table2 where *not exists* a matching record in table3. I consider the left outer join a trick rather than the straight-forward way.

Comment: You're correct. I've just had too many instances of people doing LEFT JOINS, then ruining it with a condition. That a check for `NULL` won't do that escaped me, but much like you I find that solution less readable. :)

Comment: If he doesn't need any records from table3 then this is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

A Left join on the 3rd table and the condition `WHERE  C.eventid IS NULL` should do the work.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   table1 A 
       INNER JOIN table2 B 
                    ON A.eventid = B.eventid 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 C 
                    ON A.eventid = C.eventid 
WHERE  C.eventid IS NULL
```